# ASP.NET Core Identity - Make tokens (email confirmation, password reset, etc) valid across different servers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am creating an authentication service using ASP.NET Core Identity and IdentityServer4. It is all working OK generally but I am having an issue due to the fact that in our live environment it is hosted across multiple servers, in which case a token (such as a password reset token) that is generated on one server is not valid on another.

I am setting up identity like so (custom user stores etc registered elsewhere):

```
 services.AddDataProtection()
     .SetApplicationName("IdentityService");

 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
 {
     options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
 })
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

As you can see I have tried setting the application name so it is the same on each server, however this has not solved the issue.

I have found that [I can create an IXmlRepository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/extensibility/key-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ixmlrepository) which will be used to store the keys used by Identity:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
     .SetApplicationName("IdentityService");
     .AddKeyManagementOptions(s => s.XmlRepository = new CustomXmlRepo());
```

If I implement this and store the keys in our database, will that solve my issue? Is there any other (better) way?

Comment: Distirbuted memory cache https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ???

Comment: @Tseng how can be the distributed memory cache helpful for ASP.NET Core Data Protection (AddDefaultTokenProviders), or I'm missing something

Comment: Then I seem fail to understand the question or the problem. There are different providers such as `.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem` or `.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault` etc. Same for components using memory caches usually depend on `IDistributedCache`, whose default implementation is (local) In-memory cache. By adding Redis it automatically enables apps to scale to multiple instances. Both - data protection and memory cache - configurable out of the box with asp.net core so, so not sure why an own implementation is needed in the first place

Comment: [AddDefaultProviders](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/0a0e1ea0cdbe29f2fcd2291b900db98597387d77/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityBuilderExtensions.cs#L21-L32) just registers the token generation services and doesn't say anything on where its stored

Answer (score 1):

This article covers what you need to do to make an `identityserver4` implementation production ready - amongst the requirements is shared and persistent storage of data protection keys:

IdentityServer4 guidance: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/deployment.html

Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Implementing your own method is absolutely fine - just be sure to ensure that wherever they are stored is adequately protected.